# Trajectories of Differential Equation Systems with Complex Eigenvalues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In an autonomous system of 1st order differential equations in order to find the trajectories one must solve

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{Ax+By}{Cx+Dy}$$

In the case of complex eigenvalues my notes say that the trajectories are found using

$$\ln (k\cdot x)=\frac{1}{2}\ln[(\omega-a)^{2}+b^{2}]-\frac{a}{b}\arctan\frac{\omega-a}{b}$$

where

$$\omega=\frac{Cx+iDx}{x}$$

I can't find how this relation occurs. How the $\arctan$ term came to being?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{Ax+By}{Cx+Dy}=\frac{A+By/x}{C+Dy/x}$$

Now substitute $y=xz$ and $y'=z+xz'$

$$z+xz'=\frac{A+Bz}{C+Dz}$$
$$xz'=\frac{A+Bz}{C+Dz}-z$$

This ODE is seprable.

Edit: $\arctan(x) = \frac{1}{2i} \log(\frac{x-i}{x+i})$.

Comment: I know that and I have reached to a point where I get the ln term but I can't figure out how the arctan term is produced.

Comment: Maybe that helps: $\arctan(x) = \frac{1}{2i} \log(\frac{x-i}{x+i})$

Answer (score 0):

If $y=vx$ then
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=x\frac{dv}{dx}+v=\frac{Ax+Bvx}{Cx+Dvx}=\frac{A+Bv}{C+Dv}$$
$$x\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{A+Bv}{C+Dv}-v=\frac{A+Bv-Cv-Dv^2}{C+Dv}=-\frac{v^2-\frac{B-C}Dv-\frac DA}{v+\frac CD}$$
$$\frac{v+\frac CD}{v^2-\frac{B-C}Dv-\frac DA}dv=\frac{\left(v-\frac{B-C}{2D}\right)+\frac{B+C}{2D}}{\left(v-\frac{B-C}{2D}\right)^2-\left(\frac{B-C}{2D}\right)^2-\frac DA}dv=-\frac{dx}x$$
Then we can use the formula
$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2+b^2}=\frac1b\tan^{-1}\frac xb+C$$
And the fact that the eigenvalue is complex so
$$-\left(\frac{B-C}{2D}\right)^2-\frac DA=b^2$$
And let
$$\frac{B-C}{2D}=a$$
To get
$$\frac12\ln\left((v-a)^2+b^2\right)+\frac{B+C}{2Db}\tan^{-1}\frac{v-a}{b}=-\ln x+C_1=-\ln(kx)$$
So there are similarities with what you've got, but in general
$$\frac{B+C}{2D}\ne-a=\frac{C-B}{2D}$$
And here I have $v=\frac yx$ instead of $\omega$ as you have and also $-\ln(kx)$ rather than $\ln(kx)$ but I hope this can be viewed as progress in any case.